# Syntax explanation: square brackets in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm studying Swift and got confusing with following syntax:

```
var treasures: [Treasure] = []
```

Treasure is custom class, declared as follow:

```
class Treasure: NSObject { }
```

In Objective-C square brackets mean method, but what do they mean in Swift?

Comment: this is an array. the line var treasures: [Treasure] = [] declares an array, named treasures which is supposed to hold objects of Treasure class and initialize it with an empty array

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, this is the meaning of

```
var treasures: [Treasure] = []
```

- **var**: you are declaring a variable
- **treasures**: the name of your variable
- **[Treasure]**: the type of your variable, in this case the type is Array of Treasure, the compiler will allow you to insert only object of type Treasure in your Array
- **[]**: the actual object (Array) referenced by your variable, in this case an empty Array.

E.g. if you want the Array to hold 2 elements you can write

```
var treasures: [Treasure] = [Treasure(), Treasure()]
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**
My example can also be written this way

```
var treasures = [Treasure(), Treasure()]
```

Infact thanks to the ***Type Inference*** the compiler can deduce the type of the variable ***treasures*** looking at the type of the assigned value.

Comment: Thank, i love that explanation, please tell me, will compiler forbid me to insert any other types in array (not treasure)? How to declare "simple" NSMutableArray without type restrictions?

Comment: You're welcome. You can create an array of "AnyObject". It's protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. This allows you to write something like this ***var things : [AnyObject] = ["Hello world", 1, Treasure()]***

Comment: About the ***mutable*** Array please note that you create a mutable array if you declare it using the ***var*** keyword (as you did). Instead you declare an immutable array is you use the keyword ***let***.

Answer (score 16):

`[Treasure]` **is just a syntax sugar** for `Array<Treasure>`.

The same way `[String:Treasure]` is just a syntax sugar for `Dictionary<String,Treasure>`.

`[]` **is just an empty array** of the type you defined. The same way `[:]` is an empty dictionary.

When it comes to Swift and square brackets, the rules are simple. They are used only in two situations:

1) **working with Array and Dictionary** types:

```
let vectors : [[Int]] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
let birthBook : [Int:[String]] = [1987:["John","William"], 1990: ["Mary"]]
```

2) for **subscripting objects** that support subscripting:

```
class RouteMapper {

    private var routeMap : [String:String] = [:]

    subscript(endpoint: String) -> String {
        get {
            if let route = routeMap[endpoint] {
                return route
            }
            return "/"
        }
        set(newValue) {
            routeMap[endpoint] = newValue
        }
    }
}

let routeMapper = RouteMapper()
routeMapper["users"] = "/v1/confirmed/users"
let url = routeMapper["admins"]
```

Since `[` and `]` are not allowed in custom operators, these are the only usages for now.

Comment: I found this answer by trying to look into how XCTAssertEqual(expression1: [T : U], expression2: [T : U]) works. Is this the third possibility for square brackets? I don't know the meaning of them in XCTAssertEqual. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @LiweiZ There's nothing special about them. It's just that expression1 and expression2 are of type Dictionary<T,U>. T and U are generic types for this particular variant of XCTAssertEqual.

Comment: What about Sets?